# PHP mail script fails when sending it uri encoded JSON in the message

Tags: php, email

Here is my PHP script. It's in a state of trial and error. I masked some data.

```
<?php
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
$to = "********@gmail.com";
$decodedJson = urldecode($message);
$headers = "From: ****@ericd.net\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ****@ericd.net\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
//$headers .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";

if (mail($to, $subject, $decodedJson, $headers)) {
    echo "OK. we sent " . $decodedJson;
} else {
    echo "Failed";
}
?>
```

When I curl to the PHP script with with something simple, it works.

```
curl --data "subject=Hello%20There&message=Testing" http://******/script.php
```

That works. Within a minute I get the email. Now when I have a JSON string I URI encode and send to the script, I get a success but the email never sends. Example of just part of the string:

```
curl --data "subject=Hello%20There&message=%7B%22Project%22%3A%22Eames%20II%20Purchase%20Journey%22%2C%22Description%22%3A%22Scenario..." http://******/script.php
```

The script echos the message to the terminal - looks good. Just never sends. I want to include the JSON as a simple string in the email.

Example of some of the JSON (valid)  string:

```
{"Project":"Eames II Purchase Journey","Description":"Scenario...
```

???

Comment: You don't need to call `urldecode()`. PHP does that automatically when it puts the parameters in `$_POST`.

Comment: PHP doesn't care about the URL decoding when sending mail. I suspect a spam filter is rejecting it.

Comment: Check your Gmail spam box.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP mail function doesn't complete sending of e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail)

Comment: It seems if the message is short it sends. If it’s longer, it succeeds but never is received. I’m using Go Daddy as my host and their admin is horrific.